# pub get throws a git fetch error when trying to get dependencies

Tags: git, dart, dart-pub

This is the error received:

```
C:\code\workspace\test_app_polymer>pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: git fetch
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

It seems that whatever it is looking at, at that point is not a git repo.

The command I used to clone my repo was, with a modified domain name :

```
git clone -v git@git.foo.com:ng-incubator/test_app_polymer.git .
```

So to me cloning this and then being able to do pub get should work.  Now, the next step would be to look at the dependencies which are attempted.

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  url: any
  uuid: any
  tw_portal:
    git:
      url: git@git.foo.com:portal_ng/portal_dart.git
      ref: master
  tw_ui_polymer:
    git:
      url: git@git.foo.com:portal_ng/ui_polymer
      ref: master
```

If you can take a look, it shows `ui_polymer` is not defined as a .git, so I ran it an additional time, with:
  `url: it@git.foo.com:ng_portal/ui_polymer.git` to see if that works.  It took longer to run before failing.... So that means at least there was more computation.

Am I following these steps correctly for debugging?  I was informed that the Server was updated recently, so there is a chance it is entirely a server error and not even client side.  Does anyone have any speculation as to what I may do to continue to debug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 2 issues i needed to address.  the concept of pub get.  When i was doing it, it was not giving me a password spot to enter in things like IntelliJ.  So because of this, I removed the password.  Dont worry it isnt my normal id_rsa, but instead just a little dev one.

Anyways, now that it wont pass the password into Git, that part is resolved, but there is one issue.  The Cache is saved with the failed password get, and because of that will continue to fail.

**Clear the Cache** is a key part.  I noticed this cache was in, for my account:

```
C:\Users\fallenreaper\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\cache\
```

As you can see, this is in fact a windows machine.  I was not sure *which* of the structures were jacked up, so i just deleted them all.

Now, back to cmd (or intelliJ).  You cleared the cache and you have no password.  Now you can *Get Dependencies* or run `pub get` in the dev folder (I do just inside of the root folder).

It will pull, update, and do all the compilings you need and you are ready to go.  The final step is to Build and then Open With... Dartium.

*Edit* The password i am talking about is in relation to the id-rsa key i was leveraging when cloning this project down

Comment: There is the `pub cache repair` command which usually fixes cache issues

Comment: Im going to keep this in mind for next time.  Should cut down on build times.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug introduced recently and already fixed AFAIK. Until you get the updated version just add `.git`

```
url: git@git.foo.com:portal_ng/ui_polymer.git
```

I think this should fix it.

Comment: I tried, it actually wasnt the issue.  I did figure it out though.  Ill put up the answer, and boy is it weird.  Really, all i end up needing to do is to clear the cache and use a id_rsa key that doesnt have a passphrase.  Seems there is partially corrupt git repos.